# c++ check that templates parameters are derived from a certain base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

How can I check whether my template parameters are derived from a certain base class? So that I am sure that the function Do can be called:

```
template<typename Ty1> class MyClass
{
  ...
  void MyFunction();
}; 

template<typename Ty1> void MyClass<Ty1>::MyFunction()
{
  Ty1 var;
  var.Do();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't. If the method `Do()` doesn't exist in the class provided as an argument for `Ty1`, it will simply not compile.

Templates are a form of [*duck typing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) : the abilities of a class are not determined by what interface it inherits from, but by what functionality it actually exposes.

The advantage is that your template can then be used by *any* class with a suitable `Do()` method, regardless of where it came from or what bases it has.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this using standard type trait is_base_of. Look at the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
        void foo () {}
};

class A : public Base {};
class B : public Base {};
class C {};


void exec (false_type) {
        cout << "your type is not derived from Base" << endl;
}

void exec (true_type) {
        cout << "your type is derived from Base" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void verify () {
        exec (typename is_base_of<Base, T>::type {});
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
        verify<A> ();
        verify<B> ();
        verify<C> ();

        return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
your type is derived from Base
your type is derived from Base
your type is not derived from Base
```

Comment: Isn't the tag dispatching a bit superfluous ?